# Object not keeping the scale after playing an animation in Unity

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I have an animation that scales an object down when it 'sleeps'

When the object wakes back up again, there is a 'wake' animation that scales the object back up to normal.

When the object sleeps, I also set it's game object as inactive. When it wakes up I set it as active.

The first time that this animation plays, the object stays at the normal scale.

However, When it wakes up after dying, the wake animation plays, but the scale does not stay. The object scales back down immediately after the animation for some reason.

Here is my animator component on the object:

[image]

Is there a better way to set something so simple up? Right now I am just saying in my script:

```
anim.SetTrigger(sleepAnimationTriggerName);
```

The object is a prefab, and there are at least 15 of them in the scene at any given time.

I have tried resetting the scale when the object sleeps, by storing the `transform.localescale` of the object and resetting it  in the `OnDisable()` method. This didn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just **Uncheck** the checkbox **Write Defaults** in the *Idle Animations*:

[image]

Comment: I have that box checked for both my 'wake' and 'sleep' animations. I actually had to uncheck that in my 'Idle' animator component.

Comment: @BenjaFriend Sorry i always invert the meaning of this indicator, i will update my answer to **Uncheck** then. And yes you need to apply this to your Idle state :)

Comment: Thanks! This has been bugging me for hours hehe :)

Comment: @BenjaFriend had same problem... Why is it not **Unchecked** by default...

Comment: Not work for me on unity 2021.3.5 ! why?